# How should I store leftover uncooked lasagna sheets?

Tags: storage-method, lasagna

I bought a package of [these Delverde](http://piccolosgastronomia.com/pasta/delverde/delverde-instant-spinach-lasagna-ondine-108) "no-precooking" lasagna sheets and used half a dozen to make a lasagna. Now I've got nine sheets leftover—and I don't make lasagna *that* often.

How can I store these noodles for the long term? I keep most uncooked pasta in glass jars in my pantry, but what about these big sheets?

Comment: Wrap it tight with cling film, or leave it loose in the box. You're not going to have an issue I wouldn't have thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything airtight is fine. If the sheets will fit in a Ziploc, that would be perfect. Another option that would certainly be big enough is a bread bag, well sealed. If you still have the box the pasta came in, you can put the bag inside the box to give the pasta a small measure of protection against breakage.

I checked with [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18364) and they didn't have anything to really add to that.